# Degrees of freedom for linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear, degrees-of-freedom

I'm reading on a text book about linear regression, and when I thought I finally understood degrees of freedom, I found a statement that made me doubt what I know so far. Well it's in the context of a simple linear regression (1 input).

> The orange, blue and green squares
>   indicate the MSEs associated with the corresponding curves in the lefthand
>   panel. A more restricted and hence smoother curve has fewer degrees
>   of freedom than a wiggly curve—note that in Figure 2.9, linear regression
>   is at the most restrictive end, with two degrees of freedom.

What degree of freedom they talking about in here? 
What I know is that: df(regression)=p with p is the number of features used. So for this case it must be 1.
df(residuals)=n-(p+1).
df(total)=n-1.
n is the sample size.
Any help on what that 2 might be? 
Here is the two panels of the figure 2.9.
[image: Right hand panel]
[image: Left hand panel]

Comment: Could you give us the full quote and name of the textbook?

Comment: Yes of course, it's from Introduction to statistical learning. The full quote is: "A more restricted and hence smoother curve has fewer degrees
of freedom than a wiggly curve—note that in Figure 2.9, linear regression
is at the most restrictive end, with two degrees of freedom."

Comment: My guess is the authors counted 1 for the intercept and 1 for the slope (aka, the 1 you took from n in your question). The orange line is straight so it should be a one-predictor regression.

Comment: I am more impressed that you understand the degrees of freedom of the locally fitting model, @YoussefEsseddiq :). Way harder to compute, too.

Comment: In the first graph, x axis is labeled "Flexibility". What does it mean? Another name for degree of freedom?

Comment: Penguin_Knight That's what i assumed at the end that, they are talking about degrees of freedom for yi hat (estimate of yi). So the intercept and slope are the ones free to vary, hence 2 dfs. Don't know how accurate is this reasoning tho.

Comment: a_statistician.. well formaly it's the degree of freedom on the x axis, but they call it flexibility for simplification matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I second @Penguin_Knight 's assertion in the comments: The second loss of d.f. comes from the intercept term in $\hat{y}=\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}x_1$. Every term you must estimate removes a degree of freedom from the residuals.

Most texts I have seen denote $\text{df(residuals)} = n - p$, where $p$ is the number of parameters you estimated in the model (so for linear regression, the number of covariates plus one).

Answer (score 1):

This is about overfitting. You can fit a higher order polynominal to the curve and archive lower MSE (1st Figure). In your case you have a simple function $f(x)$ with $x$ having 1 dimension. Now you can try to fit a linear curve $\hat f(x) = ax + b$ or a higher order polynomal like $\hat f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ using linear regression (2nd Figure). You are still learning linear parameters $a,b,c,d$ by solving $\min_{a,b,c,d}(\hat f(x) - y)^2$, hence linear regression.

However, this might overfit on the training data and perform worse on your actual use case. (1st Figure)

Comment: I think OP is asking why the simplest model appears to be a straight line but in the text it was described to have 2 degrees of freedom.

Comment: I quess you are right. Your comment is already the answer then.